# NetLogo: pair lists containing similar elements

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I wonder if anyone can help with this question for which I am a bit lost. I have turtles with three-dimensional boolean lists `[a  b  c]` where `a, b, c in {0, 1}`. I would like each turtle to create a link with another one who has `1` on all the same positions of the list. A turtle should thus identify where in its list it has `1` and look for another turtle that has `1` in the every same position. Where the original turtle has `0`, the second one can have either `1`or `0`.

That is:

Turtle 1 `[0 1 0]`

Turtle 2 `[1 1 1]`

Turtle 3 `[1 0 1]`

Turtle 4 `[0 1 1]`

Turtle 1 should create links with Turtle 2 or Turtle 4 (because both have `1` on `item 1`, the second position) but *not* with Turtle 3 since it has a `0`in that position. Turtle 4 should create a link with Turtle 2 only (`1` in the second and third positions), as should Turtle 3 (`1`in the first and third position), and Turtle 2 should be unable to create links (no turtles with `1` in all three positions).

What I have is

```
let candidate one-of turtles with [list1 = [list1] of myself]
create-link-with candidate
```

Which of course doesn't work since the turtle will look for another one that has exactly the same list (including zeros) and not one that has the same positions for `1` only. I know this should be related to `foreach`, `map`, `reduce`and `filter`but I can't quite get the syntax right...

Happy end of year to everyone

Comment: Hi @JenB Thanks for the comment. I think I understand your point but if I subtract Turtle 1 from Turtle 4, then I'll get `[0 0 -1]`, `[0 0 1]` in `abs`. The problem then is that I cannot differenciate the first zero from the second, and what I need is the turtle to be able to tell that they have the second element in common... Unless I am not understanding properly. Turtle 3 linking with Turtle 2 can work because it will give `[0 -1 0]`but I don't think there's an easy way to see when 0 happens because both have 1 or 0...

Comment: Thanks again @JenB. I have rewritten my question, hope it's clearer now... I'll try also the two-step idea :)

Comment: don't try the two step - it was not previously clear that ALL 1s had to match. I have edited the question slightly, but the two step is not relevant with that requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure someone who is better at lists will be able to do this with `reduce` or other clever tools. However, since `position` only gives the first position, I can't see any vectorised way to do this. So I have iterated with `foreach` instead.

```
to testme
  let list1 [0 1 0]
  let list2 [1 1 1]
  let list3 [1 0 1]
  let list4 [0 1 1]
  type "check 1, 2: " print match-ones list1 list2
  type "check 1, 3: " print match-ones list1 list3
  type "check 1, 4: " print match-ones list1 list4
  type "check 2, 1: " print match-ones list2 list1
  type "check 2, 3: " print match-ones list2 list3
  type "check 2, 4: " print match-ones list2 list4
  type "check 3, 1: " print match-ones list3 list1
  type "check 3, 2: " print match-ones list3 list2
  type "check 3, 4: " print match-ones list3 list4
  type "check 4, 1: " print match-ones list4 list1
  type "check 4, 2: " print match-ones list4 list2
  type "check 4, 3: " print match-ones list4 list3
end

to-report match-ones [#source #target]
  foreach range length #source
  [ x -> if item x #source = 1 and item x #target != 1
    [ report false
    ]
  ]
  report true
end
```

The reporting procedure takes the first list and simply runs through checking each item. If it's a 1 and the other list doesn't have a 1 then the procedure reports `false` (and ends without testing the others). If that never happens, the the procedure reports `true`.

The testme procedure is simply there to call the procedure and check your test data. The code is a complete model.

Comment: yes that does exactly like what I'm after! Tanks a lot, I'll get back if I struggle with it but I think I should be able to adapt it to my issue. Have a great 2020!

Comment: see my answer for a couple of alternate versions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
to-report match-ones [source target]
  if empty? source [ report true ]
  if first source = 1 and first target != 1 [ report false]
  report match-ones butfirst source butfirst target
end
```

and a version that uses `foreach` without using indexing:

```
to-report match-ones [source target]
  (foreach source target [[?s ?t] ->
    if ?s = 1 and ?t != 1 [ report false ]
  ])
  report true
end
```

I think this last version is probably clearest, but it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thanks a lot Seth, I am away from my computer but that is indeed a clear way to solve the problem (on paper the second one does indeed look clearer to me). I'll try it out asap. Best wishes for 2020